# .NET Post Request Response gets changed from 401 to 400 when upgrading from .NET 5 to .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid-connect

After updating .NET 5 to .NET 6 the Login Response of OpenIDConnect is not mapped correctly anymore - expect if the credentials are correct.

[image: Request to Login]

So the log of the Server with OpenIDConnect logs following:

```
OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher: Information: The response was successfully returned as a challenge response: {
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Der Benutzername und/oder das Passwort ist ungültig.",
  "error_uri": "
https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2095"

}.
```

When debugging the Line 98 the tokenresult is following:

[image]

And in the header you find the original response:

[image]

In .NET 5 the tokenresult has been a classic Forbidden result without this weird wwwAuthenticate header.

Do you have any idea what could have happened here?

Comment: It is possible that such change was made in the updated library.

Comment: A 400 makes sense to me when you send an invalid grant in the request.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I had to change the Authenticationscheme of OpenIdDict from

```
return Forbid(properties, OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

to

```
return Forbid(properties, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```